# Trigger when specific product is in the basket

Tags: google-tag-manager

Can I create a trigger from the gtma level that checks if a specific product or products is in the basket? More specifically, I even mean whole categories.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that. With custom JS. But that's not quite a viable tracking.

Trigger implies change, so rather than tracking when a product is in the basket, you want to track the event of adding a product to the basket.

If your situation is so severely unique that products get to the basket on their own with no actions from the users, then there are still a few ways of tracking that, but the most trivial thing to do would be just having a loop that checks what products are in the basket every few seconds and once the products change, the code would push a DL event indicating the change.

Generally, to track what products are in the basket, you will either need to parse DOM (if DOM has it), or likely have access to the cart object from the window scope. Your front-end devs should be able to expose it to you, or even push a dataLayer event when the cart changes, including the change in the event object.